# How to refer to namespaced model from related model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I would like to namespace some "fruit" models under "dessert", so I created a model subdirectory called "dessert", and put a "fruit" model there.

**app/models/dessert/fruit.rb**

```
class Dessert::Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.table_name_prefix
        'dessert_'
    end
end
```

The accompanying table is called: `dessert_fruits` and I am able to enter the rails console and successfully execute `Dessert::Fruit.all`.

Now I would like to create an association with another model (`meal.rb`) using `has_one` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but I don't know how to refer to the namespaced model (`xxxxx` below):

**app/models/meal.rb**

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :xxxxx, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :xxxxx
    # replacing :xxxxx with :dessert_fruit does not work
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the class name explicitly:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :fruit, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true, class_name: '::Dessert::Fruit'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :fruit
end
```

[This article](https://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-3-organizing-with-modules/) has a more in-depth discussion of organizing with modules.

Comment: thank you so much. your answer allowed me to continue my work. i am so grateful!